# How to pass a list of objects as global variable to module in python

Tags: python, object, module

I have a main file lets say `main.py` where I generate a list of objects (bodies):

```
bodies = [body.Body( 
                number = i, 
                length = 1., 
                mass = 10., 
                mass_moment_of_inertia = 1., 
                theta = 0., 
                omega = 0., 
                xy_force_vector = np.array([0., 0.]), 
                xy_u_F_vector = np.array([0., 0.]), 
                ground = 0, 
                limit_x = 0., 
                limit_y = 0., 
                z_moment = 0., 
                stiffness_coef = 0., 
                damping_coef = 0.) 
      for i in range(0, N)]
```

I would like to use the properties of list of objects (bodies) in (multiple) sub files/modules to calculate needed values. I have module submodule.py that has:
submodule.py

```
def fun_name():
    for i in range(0, N):
        #   joins mass of all objects in one array (this is just an example, I have to to more calculations with the object properties)
        q = bodies[i].mass.append()
    return q
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. Now I have to think trough what is the best solution of my problem. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by @Martin Pieters is the best way to do this. For completeness sake though, you could also do this:

```
from main import bodies
def fun_name():
    # ...
```

Either way, it is best to be explicit about where things are coming from in python.

Also, my example assumes that `main.py` is importable from `submodule.py`.

Comment: Building off of this, you could dynamically create a module and import it when needed.

Answer (score 1):

Globals are limited to the current module. Instead of using globals, pass in the list as a parameter:

```
def fun_name(bodies):
    # ...
```

and call `fun_name()` with your bodies list from the module that *does* define the global.

Answer (score 1):

In `main.py` add the line `import subprocess` at the beginning and than 
call your function

```
import subprocess

subprocess.fun_name(bodies) # after the definition of `bodies`
```

In `subprocess.py` modify your function `def fun_name(bodies):`

Both files need to be in the same directory to make it easy.